# How to disable asking for "(current) UNIX Password:” during a password reset?

Tags: linux, rhel

how to disable question for “(current) UNIX Password:” again after user logs in using his expired password?

What I need is that after a user provides his expired password in next step he is asked immediately about providing his new password twice.

So instead of:

```
xxxxx@host's password:
You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)
Last login: Mon Oct 29 11:21:22 2018 from abcdefgh

WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Changing password for user xxxxx
(current) UNIX Password:
New password:
Retype new password:
```

there is:

```
xxxxx@host's password:
You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)
Last login: Mon Oct 29 11:21:22 2018 from abcdefgh

WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Changing password for user xxxxx
New password:
Retype new password:
```

Comment: Expiring passwords is a good way to socially engineer users to choose poor passwords, and to write them onto sticky notes.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I believe it's (still) a mandatory requirement for certifications such as PCI-DSS.

Comment: Why the downvotes people? It's a perfectly sensible question - the user would have already had to enter their password to get to this point so there's no lost security.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the distribution the behavior of the passwd command can be configured in /etc/pam.d/passwd.

Comment: How would someone use the PAM `passwd` configuration file to ask for a current password during the password reset? An example would be most helpful.